# Invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) in making PDF from WS answer XML

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm doing some report from xml, which comes from WS. Report should be in PDF format, so I've chosen fop library to make it. When I'm trying to make report from xml, which located on my computer in xml file everything works fine.
The problems start when I'm invoking this method on WebServer. I have exception on this line:

```
transformer.transform(src, res);
```

Exception is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) was found in the element content of the document.
```

First was (Unicode: 0x1a) character, but I cutted it with this function:

```
   private static String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {

    if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(in);
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length(); i++) {
        if (out.charAt(i) == 0x1a) {
            out.setCharAt(i, '-');
        }             
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

But then came (Unicode: 0x2) character. Trying to add

```
    else if (out.charAt(i) == 0x2) {
        out.setCharAt(i, '-');
    }
```

doesn't help.

I'm using fop version 0.95.

Comment: are you trying to process something from  IBM Rational RequisitePro?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, that was my stupid mistake, I just put code, which includes Cyrillic fonts after the code, which uses this.